# Как изменить логику выборки элементов (товаров) в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно товары с нулевой ценой (под заказ) выводить в конце выборки.

Конечно, можно в result_modifier.php пересобрать массив arResult, но это будет работать без учета пагинации страниц. Очевидно, нужно модифицировать сам запрос, но как это сделать без "костылей"?

Comment: *Очевидно, нужно модифицировать сам запрос* А где он, "самзапрос"-то?

Comment: для меня это пока тайна, покрытая мраком

Comment: 1) Сортировать по цене :D 2) Можно добавить обработчик на изменение цены. Если цена нулевая, то ставить значение сортировки очень большое (например, 999999) и затем в каталоге делать первую сортировку по параметру SORT

Comment: пример кода можно?

Comment: @ka3a, что значит "делать первую сортировку по параметру SORT"? Если это параметры компонента, то вроде так и есть: "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
  "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "desc",
  "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
  "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc"

Comment: @ka3a за идею с изменением индекса сортировки спасибо. Осталось определить метод изменения. Первая мысль - по крону ночью прогонять все товары

Comment: Можно по крону, да, но тогда в течение дня будет неактуальная информация выводиться на сайте

Comment: Лучше завязаться на события изменения цен, вот пример: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/events/onbeforepriceupdate.php. Рекомендую посмотреть внизу страницы комментарий Нагонова Сергея, он пишет пример кода для события на d7 (битрикс рекомендует работать с методами d7 для цен). В вашем случае думаю можно завязаться на события OnAfter, чтобы вызывать метод обновления индекса сортировки для товаров после изменения цен. Ну и ещё нужно написать скрипт, который в первый раз пробежится по всем товарам и проставит актуальные значения на данный момент

Comment: К событию привязываться смысла нет, т.к., во-первых, не нашел события after в доках, и, во-вторых, цены выгружаются из 1с прям в бд. Повесил на крон скрипт, все работает. Спасибо за идею)